# Check if the element has a certain parameter in revit api

Tags: c#, revit-api

In Revit API, when you want to get a parameter, you send its `enum` then fetch it and you convert it to the type you want.

But sometimes the parameter is missing so it return `null`, and `null.AsDouble()` or `null.AsValueString()` throws a `null exception`.

I retrieve so many parameters and I am using ternary operators but I am not sure that this is the best way to handle this

```
string typemark = e.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_TYPE_MARK)!=null?wt.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_TYPE_MARK).AsValueString():"";
double cost = e.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_COST)!=null?wt.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_COST).AsDouble():0;
```

I was thinking of doing a function that is more generic, to pass the parameter and the type that I want to convert the result to.

```
public static T CheckParameterAndFetch<T>(this Element e, BuiltInParameter p, Type t)
    {
        if (e.get_Parameter(p) != null)
        {
            if (t.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(e.get_Parameter(p).AsValueString(), typeof(string));                   
            }
            else if (t.GetType() == typeof(double))
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(e.get_Parameter(p).AsDouble(), typeof(double));
            }
            else if (t.GetType() == typeof(int))
            {                  
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType((int)e.get_Parameter(p).AsDouble(), typeof(double));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (t.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {

                return (T)Convert.ChangeType("", typeof(string));
            }
            else if (t.GetType() == typeof(double))
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(0, typeof(double));
            }
            else if (t.GetType() == typeof(int))
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(0, typeof(int));

            }
        }
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(null, typeof(string));
    }
```

and when calling it I type the following:

```
string typeName = wt.CheckParameterAndFetch(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_TYPE_NAME,typeof(string));
```

and I get this exception:

The type arguments for method 'namespace.Extensions.CheckParameterAndFetch (Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element,
Autodesk.Revit.DB.BuiltInParameter, System.Type)' cannot be inferred
from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. (CS0411)

Answer (score 1):

I think that with the latest .NET framework you can just call it like so: `var param = v.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_COST)?.AsInteger();` notice the '?' after the `get_Parameter()` call. That checks whether the parameter returned was `null` and will not call `AsInteger()` if it was `null`. Here's some more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators